# Insufficient privilege error on access contacts on account page

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, commandlink

I am using commandlink rerender to refresh a pageblock. I am making the contact name as a link here and trying to access it on the same page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" >

<apex:pageBlock title="{!account.name}">

<apex:outputpanel id="contactdetail">

<apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cid}" relatedList="false" title="false" />

</apex:outputpanel>

</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageblock title="Contacts">
<apex:datalist value="{!account.contacts}" var="contact">
<apex:form >
<apex:commandlink rerender="contactdetail">
{!contact.name}
<apex:param name="cid" value="{contact.id}"/>
</apex:commandlink>
</apex:form>
</apex:datalist>

</apex:pageblock>

</apex:page>
```

When I click the contact name here which is a link , it should just refresh the pageblock to show me the contact details page. But I get a insufficient privilege error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue as i am a new developer working with basic visual force pages.

you used

```
 <apex:param name="cid" value="{contact.id}"/>
```

instead of

```
 <apex:param name="cid" value="{!contact.id}"/>
```

Note the missing `!` inside your curly brackets (`{}`).

Answer (score 1):

There is an example of what you are attempting in the Visualforce [guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_pages_developers_guide.pdf) on page 42:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
        You are displaying contacts from the {!account.name} account.
        Click a contact's name to view his or her details.
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">
        <apex:form>
            <apex:dataTable value="{!account.Contacts}" var="contact" cellPadding="4"
border="1">
              <apex:column>
               <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
               <apex:commandLink>
                 {!contact.Name}
                 <apex:param name="cid" value="{!contact.id}"/>
               </apex:commandLink>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column>
               <apex:facet name="header">Phone</apex:facet>
               {!contact.Phone}
              </apex:column>
            </apex:dataTable>
         </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cid}" relatedList="false" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>
```

Side note: you have your datalist tag outside of the form, should be inside the form tags.

Comment: You are right, this is from the Visualforce workbook. It works fine when I copied your code, but with my code it does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: @Rdvsm what are you trying to accomplish by changing it?

Comment: Well, I just wrote the code on my own with only using some tags but not all. I wanted to see if these tags are inter dependent on each other to execute. May that is why my code dint work?